# How to get the days between current_date and the time filed in Hive?

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp

There are two time-stamp filed in mytable:

'regdate', for example '`20120719044326`', is in the format of bigint;
'subscr_date', for example '`2012-07-19 04:43:26`', is in the format of national character varying..

I want to get the days between current_date and regdate as reg_days; the days between current_date and subscr_date as subscr_days..

So how to write query in Hive?

Comment: both regdate & subscr_date are indicating to same date?

Answer (score 0):

If regdate and subscr_date are String:

```
select datediff(current_date,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(unix_timestamp(regdate, 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as reg_days,
datediff(current_date,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(subscr_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as subscr_days
from mytable;
```

If regdate is a BigInt and subscr_date is a String:

```
select datediff(current_date,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(unix_timestamp(CAST(regdate AS STRING), 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as reg_days,
datediff(current_date,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(subscr_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as subscr_days
from mytable;
```

if **regdate** and **subscr_date** are 2012-07-19 and **current_date** is 2016-09-01 the result is:

**reg_days** 1504 **subscr_days** 1504